# Is there a way to use contains any function in grouped query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a need to create needed table in description from my data tables FRUIT_TRANSPORT (fact) and FRUIT (dimension). For me the data duplicates and I can't figure this out.

FRUIT_TRANSPORT:

[image: FRUIT_TRANSPORT]

FRUIT:

[image: FRUIT]

NEEDED TABLE:

[image: Needed table]

Comment: Pictures? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  t.receipt,
  case when count(case when f.fruit_color = 'YELLOW' then 1 end) > 0
      then 'yes' else 'no' end as has_yellow,
  case when count(case when f.fruit_color = 'GREEN' then 1 end) > 0
      then 'yes' else 'no' end as has_green,
  sum(t.amount) as amount  
from fruit_transport t
join fruit f on f.fruit_id = t.fruit_id
group by t.receipt
```

Answer (score 1):

As a slight variation on the earlier answer, you could produce the 'yes' string in the `case when` expression, take the maximum in the group, and use `coalesce` to give a default value of 'no':

```
select receipt,
       coalesce(max(case fruit_color when 'YELLOW' then 'yes' end), 'no') has_yellow,
       coalesce(max(case fruit_color when 'GREEN'  then 'yes' end), 'no') has_green,
       sum(amount) amount
from   fruit f
inner join fruit_transport ft on f.fruit_id = ft.fruit_id
group by receipt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was also very helpful as I haven't been using coalesce before so I learned something completely new here.